# What we know about $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> What we know about $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a group? Are there any interesting properties?

Best regards.

Comment: As a group it is both divisible and torsion.

Comment: Can you please reopen the question? I do not know exactly what "too broad" means in this case? I added "as a group" to be more specific. Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the torsion group of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$
- $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible
- $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $S^{1}$
- $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique subgroup of order $n$ for every $n$
- $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely generated

Comment: $\bullet$ $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: $\bullet$ $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \bigoplus_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, nice. Vote to reopen and add your own answer...

Comment: $\bullet$ $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is an injective cogenerator of $\mathsf{Mod}(R)$.